# How to queue two functions

Tags: jquery, queue

A beginners question- how do I make fadeIn play only after slideDown is complete?

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

          $(".clickme").click(function() { 

              $(".content").slideDown();
              $(".hi").fadeIn();     

          });

      });
```

I tried using functions inside of functions and queue but it did not work or my syntax was wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) for the usage of the `complete` parameter

Answer (score 0):

The slideDown function comes with a "Complete" function in its parameters, which you can use to call the fade in upon completing the slide down.

The following should do the trick..

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".clickme").click(function() {

             $(".content").slideDown(function() {
                 $(".hi").fadeIn();
             });

         });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `fadeIn` to the `slideDown` like so

```js
$(".content").slideDown(function() {
  $(".hi").fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='content' hidden>
  THIS CONTAINS CONTENT
</div>
<div class='hi' hidden>
  HELLO WORLD
</div>
```